# Elasticsearch indexing performance issues

Tags: elasticsearch

We are facing some performance issues with elasticsearch in the last couple of days. As you can see on the screenshot, the indexing rate has some significant drops after the index reaches a certain size. At normal speed, we index arround 3000 logs per second. When the index we write to reaches a size of about ~10 GB, the rate drops.

We are using time based indices and arround 00:00, when a new Index is created by Logstash, the rates climb again to ~3000 logs per second (thats why we think its somehow related to the size of the index).

Server stats show nothing unusal at the CPU or memory stats (they are the same during drop-phases), but one of the servers has alot of I/O waits. Our Elasticsearch config is quite standard, with some adjustments to index performance (taken from the ES guide):

```
# If your index is on spinning platter drives, decrease this to one
# Reference / index-modules-merge
index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count: 1
# allows larger segments to flush and decrease merge pressure
index.refresh_interval: 5s
# increase threshold_size from default when you are > ES 1.3.2
index.translog.flush_threshold_size: 1000mb
# JVM settings
bootstrap.mlockall: true (ES_HEAP SIZE is 50% of RAM)
```

We use two nodes. Both with 8 GB of RAM, 2 CPU cores and 300GB HDD size (dev environment).

I already saw clusters with alot bigger indices than ours. Do you guys have any idea what we could do to fix the issues?

BR

**Edit:**
Just ran into the performance issues again. **Top** sometimes shows arround 60% wa (wait), but **iotop** only reports about 1000 K/s read and write at max. I have no idea where these waits are coming from.

[image: Marvel]